# ORACLE REPORT : REP-1814: The report cannot be formatted. Object vertically cannot fit within location B_15

Tags: java, oracle, oraclereports

I'm working on an Oracle report in Oracle report builder and it shows no error in oracle report builder,
but when I run the report on a web browser it returns this error:
"REP-1814: The report cannot be formatted. Object vertically cannot fit within location B_15."
What does it mean? How can I resolve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're designing your Reports on your PC on Windows operating system, and sending to an application server on a Unix based operating system, you might encounter such an issue, I suppose due to mismatch among *units' configuration* between those platforms.

There's a suggested workaround by Oracle support to surpass this problem with a tool called `rwconverter.sh` provided by Oracle. According to that :

- convert your `rdf` file to a `rex` file by `rwconverter.sh`
- most probably you'll see a literal `FONTSIZE = 0`, replace all
  occurrences to `FONTSIZE = 1200` as a suggested value.
- and then convert it to the original type, i.e. `rdf`

Answer (score 0):

You said that it works in Reports Builder but not in web browser. Did you run it with the same data set (same parameters, same tables, same data stored within)?

Because, I have an impression that Reports Builder used "testing" data and worked fine, but in production it failed.

The error you got - that

> Object vertically cannot fit within location B_15

means that you want to put something "big" into a "small" B_15 (what is B_15? Is it a frame?).

"Vertically" might be a keyword here, meaning that you should modify B_15's **vertical elasticity** property and set it to "**variable**" or "expand"; I presume it is set to "fixed" (which is the default).

I'd suggest you to try it and see what happens.